# Mysql select statement with inner join not working with php but works on mysql terminal

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in mysql

**Table 1: projects**

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------+
| id | ProjectName | ProjectDescription          | projType | projectStatus |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | RAPepsi     | Retail Audit for Pepsi      |        1 |             1 |
|  2 | RACocaco    | Retail Audit for Coke       |        1 |             1 |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------------+
```

**Table2 : outlets**

```
id pid  poid OutletName Add1     Add2       City    Phone  interviewer Status projStat 
    1   1   11  Outlet1 Address1    Address2    City1   12345      1          1      1
    2   1   21  Outlet2 Address1    Address2    City1   12345      1          1      1
    3   2   32  Outlet2 Address1    Address2    City1   12345      3          1      1
```

**Table 3: Users**

```
id  username        email           password
1   test1@gmail.com test1@gmail.com 123
2   test2@gmail.com test2@gmail.com 123
3   test3@gmail.com test3@gmail.com 123
```

I am trying to get the project name and description from projects table assigned to specfic interviewer from outlets table.  I have tried this code in mysql console:

```
select distinct(p.ProjectName),p.ProjectDescription from outlets as oo inner join projects as p on p.id = oo.pid where oo.interviewer=(select id from users where email='test1@gmail.com');
```

This fetches the correct results as desired.  However, when I use the same code in a php script where the email is dynamic, it fails to return the data:

**PHP Script**

```
include "config.php";
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$username  = (isset($_GET['userId']))?  $_GET['userId'] : 0;
$sql="select distinct(p.ProjectName),p.ProjectDescription from outlets as oo inner join projects as p on p.id = oo.pid where oo.interviewer=(select id from users where email='".$username."')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

**The above line not working in php**.  I am getting the following error:  [client 103.47.158.210:56346] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE)

However, when i use the following code: it works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects where projectStatus=1 and username= '".$username."'";
```

Ofcourse I test this with username column in my projects table.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error, there's nothing wrong with the code you have posted. Are you sure it's on this line: `$result = $conn->query($sql);`?

Comment: @nick yes...it is on that line it fails...

Comment: Normally that error would indicate a missing `;` at the end of the previous line but that is there. the code has no syntax errors on 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/QZ1pG

Comment: Side notes: `DISTINCT` is not a function, you can remove the parenthesis around `p.ProjectName`, they have no effect. And your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use parameterized queries. See: ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Im suspecting that this line is the issue here:

```
$username = (isset($_GET['userId'])) ? $_GET['userId'] : 0;
```

This line is telling me that you are trying to get the user id (which I'm guessing is a number) and then query the database for an email (which is a string).
Try setting `$username` to `test1@gmail.com` and see if that works for you. If that works, then you know you need to be getting that users `username` rather than their `id`.

The other way you could do it would be to query the database for the user's `id` instead of their `email`.
So this would be your new PHP line:

```
$sql="select distinct(p.ProjectName),p.ProjectDescription from outlets as oo inner join projects as p on p.id = oo.pid where oo.interviewer=(select id from users where id='".$username."')";
```

If neither of those ways work, then double check that you are connecting to the correct database and try again.

Good luck!